# Shrinking Nav bar based on Media Screens/Screen Width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I was wondering if it is possible to have my nav bar shrink based on media screens. Like lets say i want my nav bar to only show up at a certain height for desktops and for laptops I want it to show up with a smaller certain height. Or to disable some elements in HTML based on media screens

Any help or comments would help me out a lot!

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, Google "css media queries".

Comment: @DanielWilliams Also is it possible to setup a script to shrink a nav bar and no to shrink a nav bar based on the webpages size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below breaks at 770px, 576px and 500px.
Each break will change the navs background-color, except the 500, which will remove it.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
}

@media (max-width: 770px) {
  nav {
    background-color: aquamarine;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  nav {
    background-color: burlywood;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
```